# Images take a long time to load phonegap application on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm loading a set of thumbnails into a list in a phonegap application dynamically. This is the function I use to load the images:

```
var getUserImage = function(src) {
    // render the users profile image
    var $profileImage;
    if ( typeof src ==='undefined' || src === 'placeholder.jpg' || src === '') {
        // avoid hitting the server
        $profileImage = $('<img />', {
            class: 'profile-image responsive-image',
            src: 'img/placeholder.png'
        });
    } else {
        var imgSrc = $.app.config.imagePath + src + '?width=200&height=200&crop=auto';

        $profileImage = $('<img />', {
            class: 'profile-image responsive-image',
            src: imgSrc
        }).one('error', onImageLoadError);
    }

    return $profileImage;
};
```

I modified the else statement to do a console.log on the images load event. Images (each around 10-15KB) take over a minute to load! This isn't a server issue, it works absolutely find in my browser and on Android. It's just iOS that's taking forever.

Comment: Have you tried benchmarking what bit of code is actually taking the longest?

Comment: None of the code is running slow. It's the image loading that's working show. I tried pointing the image to Google's logo and it loaded just fine. So basically it works fine if it's on my dev machine and it works fine if it loads from Google's servers but not on the iPhone loading from our servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was exceeding the number of requests the safari browser could handle. We use long polling in our application and the safari web view limits the number of concurrent connections to a single domain.

The solution was simple. Serve our images from a different domain (or subdomain) to the ones we use to access the API. This way you can increase the number of concurrent connections you can make.